# Is this a typo in the Polymer 1.x documentation: ${foo}?

Tags: data-binding, syntax, polymer, polymer-1.0

[The third paragraph of this page of Polymer documentation reads this](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document):

```
/users/${userId}/notes/${noteId}
```

The paragraph above it reads this:

```
/users/{{userId}}/notes/{{noteId}}
```

I've never seen the first syntax before `${foo}` for data bindings. Is it correct? Or is this a typo?

[The data bindings documentation here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding), don't mention that syntax. It suggests the proper syntax should look like `{{foo}}`.

So is `/users/${userId}/notes/${noteId}` correct? Does it mean something? Or is it just a typo in the documentation?

Comment: [JavaScript syntax sugar called *template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/users/${userId}/notes/${noteId}
```

is JavaScript string interpolation. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
/users/{{userId}}/notes/{{noteId}}
```

Is Polymer binding expression